# SQL Azure Full Text Search and noise words

Tags: azure-sql-database

Tinkering with a plugin for using Full Text Search on `SQL Azure`, and I'm having a problem with noise words, especially when using `CONTAINSTABLE`.

Logs of real-world search queries for our sites indicate that I need to deal with the noise words one way or the other.  What I would like to do is set 'transform noise words' [as referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838985/full-text-search-using-freetexttable-failing-on-noise-words-sql-server-2008-r2) but `sp_configure` appears to not be allowed.

Is there another way to enable this feature, or are their other options I should be considering to deal with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try creating new stoplist and build index using that? You can add noise words to that

Comment: Thanks for that.  Didn't solve the problem, but it gave me a workaround.  After duplicating the system stoplist I was able to extract a distinct list of the English words.  I'm using those in an array_diff to remove them from queries before submitting them to SQL.  Still need a way to do it properly with the default list, though, so it will support all languages easily.

Answer (score 0):

Changing configuration options for full-text service is not available in Azure SQL Database as mentioned here (see limitations section):
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/30/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/.
A database scoped configuration option similar to instance level configuration with sp_configure is still in the works for Azure SQL Database.

Comment: So what is the recommended workaround for noise words in the mean time?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to use [sys.dm_fts_parser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280463.aspx) to filter out the noise words from your search term. For the search term

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

And then use this

```
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ' ' + display_term FROM sys.dm_fts_parser (' "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" ', 1033, 0, 0)
    WHERE special_term<>'Noise Word'
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1,1,'');
```

Gives you

```
quick brown fox jumps lazy dog
```

Of course it would be better if the config option was supported in Azure...